# Displaying results in View linq to sql mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been reading and reading , and I can't seem to get this to work at all.  I am very very new to asp.net MVC - after all the tutorials I read I finally got this much accomplished.

```
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    private EventsDBDataContext db = new EventsDBDataContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var a = (from x in db.tblEvents
                 where x.StartDate >= DateTime.Now
                 select x).Take(20).ToList();
        return View(a);
    }
}
```

This is successfully finding 20 rows (like it is supposed to).  Now how do I display these in the view ?? Does it have to be a strongly typed view?? It doesn't seem like it should have to be... I have tried both , I tried typing a whole view, but for now it would be nice to just get one property of `tblEvents` to show up in the view.  This is not working, I have tried many many variations.

```
@{foreach( var item in Model){

      @Html.DisplayFor( item.ID)

  }
}
```

How do I get the results from the controller displayed in the view?  Just the `ID` is good for now - I can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your View doesn't know what type your Model is. Use the @model syntax to define the type of your model.

```
@model List<YourEventClass>

@foreach( var item in Model )
{
   @item.ID<br />
}
```

See i.e. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/13/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-strongly-typed-views-in-razor.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 0):

from the root of the web project you should have a directory called `Views`. Within the views folder create a new folder named `Events`. In the `Events` folder create a razor view named `Index`. put your markup and template code in this file.

You are correct, views do not need to be strongly typed. I find it's a good idea to do so because it provides another compile time check, but it's not required.

when you run the application you will navigate from the root (typically home/index) to Events/Index. there you should see the list of 20 items rendered in the view.

Comment: I got that much - it was displaying the right View -  I found out the problem was that the view didn't know what type Model was.  Adding @model IEnumerable<GetEvents.Models.tblEvent>   in the view made it work

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can not do something like this:

```
@{foreach( var item in Model){
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
 }
```

unless the view  knows what Type Model is returned as (still seems weird that .Net can't figure that out on its own.  So I fixed the problem and got the ID displayed properly by adding this to the View.

```
@model IEnumerable<GetEvents.Models.tblEvent>
```

This works fine for this example - I am returning one table , so the Model type is just the class for the table.  But this doesn't seem right - what if I wanted to query and join tables then what would the Model Type be?? Adding this fixed my problem , but if someone has a better answer for this then I will accept that.